# UITextView: Automatically break line when reached a fixed width

Tags: swift, dynamic, view, width, uitextview

I'm working on a view which holds a UITextView. Estimating the correct height for the content works just fine but when continuously typing the content grows horizontally over the border. Which looks like this:

[image]

Is there any handy solution which automatically breaks the line when reaching the, through auto layout, defined max width ?

Comment: Possible workaround : in the attribute inspector, set "lines" to 2 or more.

Comment: I'm working with UITextView which have no 'lines' attribute

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with is a pretty simple approach:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let size = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.frame.size)
    if size.width >= self.maxTextViewWidth {
        let subString = textView.text.suffix(1)
        textView.text.removeLast(1)
        textView.text.append(contentsOf: "\n" +  subString)
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: After paste a long text, every character typing will make a new line

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix a limit of caracters or number of lines, you can by implementing a method from `UITextView` delegate called `func textView(UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn: NSRange, replacementText: String)`

Comment: This behavior is not exactly what I'm looking for. I want my application to add a line break to the text where it would instead grow over the border